# How to fix a broken Opera profile?

Tags: ubuntu, opera

I've done something in my Opera profile (maybe deleted many RSS items or subscribed to a new one) that completely broke Opera. Now when I run it, it consumes 100% RAM and quickly saturates the swap file.

In the profile, I use email and RSS feeds. I tried `sudo opera`, it runs normally.

How can I fix this?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1, Opera 12.11.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but I just came across your question...

If you delete Opera's profile file, it will automatically create a default one when it starts up. That should fix your problem. I've done this a couple of times in the past, when I couldn't be bothered to figure out what the reason was for weird behaviour. It works like a charm.

According to [this page](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafilesnix/), the profile file (opera6.ini) under linux is in ~/.opera

Comment: I see that profiles are no longer kept in  ~/.opera  since that no longer exists opera 42 ... Any idea where new profiles are stored ?  ubuntu

Comment: If you go to Menu > About Opera it shows the location (at least, the Windows version does)